# Alert seemed to work during trading hours but hasn't worked since close

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am new to trading view. I just set up my first alert and find it pretty cool.
All was good until I was making adjustments after close today when my alerts stopped working. I tried searching this but couldn't find anything.

I assume its how my code is assembled but am having a hard time figuring out why.

my alert is simply taking three variables: the daily open, daily close, and 9ema. If the open is below the 9ema and the close is above the 9ema I wanted to send alert.

The test ticker I have tried using is $PEAR which I believe met the conditions.

```
indicator("Close above 9EMA on the daily")

daily_open = open
daily_close = close

ema_9 = ta.ema(close, 9)

buy = ((daily_open < ema_9) and (daily_close > ema_9))
if buy
    alert('{"content":"' + syminfo.ticker + ',\nType: Buy Signal"}', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

plot(daily_close, color = color.new(color.green,0))
plot(ema_9, color = color.new(color.blue,0))
plot(daily_open, color = color.new(color.red,0))
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused - the market closed, so trading is closed for the day. Why would your code send an alert when the market isn't open? Are you backtesting?

Comment: hmm.. i guess i want an alert so that i can add a ticker to a watchlist to be traded for the next trading day. So are you saying you cant set up something to alert after the close?

Answer (score 0):

Your alert will be triggered when the bar is closed due to `alert.freq_once_per_bar_close`.

There won't be a new bar until the new trading session starts. So, there is no bar that could trigger another alert after the market is closed.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense. Thank you. Is there any way to test an alert like this when market is closed then? Thanks again.